# Delete a quote (") from vector in R

Tags: r

I have the following problem:

I have a vector with `c("FRA, "GER, "RUS)` and I want to delete the " " " in order to get `c(FRA, GER, RUS)`.
I already tried `sub(""", "", x)` and `str_extract(x, """)` but R does not accept """ as an argument in neither cases...

Can you help me?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a couple of ways to extract the double quote, one using a single ' to quote the double quote, and another using the backslash. Both work:

```
aVector <- c('"FRA', '"GER', '"RUS')
```

We print the vector to illustrate the extra " in each element. It is represented as \" in the output.

```
> aVector
[1] "\"FRA" "\"GER" "\"RUS"
>
```

Now, use the `sub()` function to remove the double quote from each element.

```
sub('"','',aVector)

sub("\"","",aVector)
```

...and the output:

```
> sub('"','',aVector)
[1] "FRA" "GER" "RUS"
> sub("\"","",aVector)
[1] "FRA" "GER" "RUS"
>
```